# X-Accel-Redirect feature does not work for external connections (inside docker network)

Tags: django, nginx, x-accel-redirect

I'm trying to allow container with django to manage access to media files served from another container with nginx. Because of that despite of nginx documentation, I've removed the `internal` line from the location config:

```
server {
    server_name nginx; //name of the container used for accessing from another containers
    charset UTF-8;
    client_max_body_size 32m;
    listen 80;

    location /protected/media/ {
        // internal;
        alias /data/djan,go/media/;
    }
}
```

With this config I'm able to use /protected/media urls from django containers so I've succeeded at doing `wget http://nginx/protected/media/images/bank_credentials/H0grsrvgsBo.jpg` from shell of container with django.

But django's code

```
response = HttpResponse()
del response['Content-Type']
response['X-Accel-Redirect'] = 'http://nginx/protected/media/' + path # I'm sure that this url matches to url I've used succesfully with wget
return response
```

returning 404
Here is the django's url:

```
path('media/<path:path>', media_access, name='media')
```

Where I'm wrong?

Comment: Did you check the URL directly with Django without Nginx inbetween?

Comment: do you really mean a comma here  `alias /data/djan,go/media/;` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you're trying to do is have `X-Accel-Redirect` with an absolute URL for an external domain/host, hence the need to remove `internal` as per http://nginx.org/r/internal to make the files accessible without authentication.  It doesn't work like that.

Take a look at the examples provided at http://nginx.org/r/proxy_pass_request_headers, for example:

```
location /x-accel-redirect-here/ {
    proxy_method GET;
    proxy_pass_request_headers off;
    proxy_pass_request_body off;

    proxy_pass ...
}
```

It'd be totally reasonable for nginx to have a requirements of having to use relative URLs in `X-Accel-Redirect`; otherwise, how would nginx know how exactly to handle the request?

---

In other words, you probably would have to use relative URLs in `X-Accel-Redirect`, and, if you require escaping into another container, to have extra `internal` `location` directives to do an explicit `proxy_pass`, as appropriate.

Note that doing this might invalidate the whole benefit of using `X-Accel-Redirect` in the first place, especially due to http://nginx.org/r/proxy_buffering being `on` by default, which causes nginx to save each proxied file onto disc, hence disc throughput may quickly become the limiting factor in your setup.